# How to make 'sign in' during checkout go to checkout instead of 'my account'?

Tags: magento2, checkout

In Magento 2, during the checkout process how do you change it so when someone signs into their account it logs them in and continues on with the checkout, rather than to re-direct them away from the checkout and into the 'My Account' page as it currently does.

Thank you

Comment: So all in all you want to redirect customer to my account page when he login from checkout page. Is it so @Ben?

Answer (score 0):

this behavior can be changed from admin:

> STORES -> Configuration -> CUSTOMERS -> Customer Configuration -> Login
>   -> Options -> Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in -> No

[image: Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in]

When doing this, you need to be careful about the store view, maybe you have a different value depending on the store view:

[image: Store view selection]

After you need to remove your cache from:

> SYSTEM -> Cache Management

[image: Cache Management]

Test again, it should work, if it doesn't work that means you have maybe some custom code installed.